# Xpages multiple file attachment conflict with partial/full update

Tags: validation, xpages, page-refresh, required, ssjs

I am using the multiple file attachment from [openntf](http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/YouAtNotes%20HTML5%20Multi%20File%20Upload%20control) but it seems it's a problem when on the same page it is a validation on a field (a required field).

When I click the button to upload the files, I get the error message on the validation field.

**Question:** How can I have some kind of "Process data without validation" on the file uploader? How can I do this with Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two possibilities to upload files without getting validation error:

1. Don't include fields with validation into the partial refresh area set by `xc:ynUploadFilesHTML5`'s parameter `refreshID`
2. Select "Process data without validation" in custom control `ynUploadFilesHTML5`'s button "refresh"